# how assign new text to the built model (text mining)

Tags: r, text-mining

yesterday i found good R code for classification emotion and took some part

```
happy = readLines("./happy.txt")
sad = readLines("./sad.txt")
happy_test = readLines("./happy_test.txt")
sad_test = readLines("./sad_test.txt")

tweet = c(happy, sad)
tweet_test= c(happy_test, sad_test)
tweet_all = c(tweet, tweet_test)
sentiment = c(rep("happy", length(happy) ), 
              rep("sad", length(sad)))
sentiment_test = c(rep("happy", length(happy_test) ), 
                   rep("sad", length(sad_test)))
sentiment_all = as.factor(c(sentiment, sentiment_test))


library(RTextTools)

mat= create_matrix(tweet_all, language="english", 
                   removeStopwords=FALSE, removeNumbers=TRUE, 
                   stemWords=FALSE, tm::weightTfIdf)

container = create_container(mat, as.numeric(sentiment_all),
                              trainSize=1:160, testSize=161:180,virgin=FALSE) 

models = train_models(container, algorithms=c("MAXENT",
                                              "SVM",
                                               #"GLMNET", "BOOSTING", 
                                               "SLDA","BAGGING", 
                                              "RF", # "NNET", 
                                              "TREE" 
                                               ))

# test the model
results = classify_models(container, models)

table(as.numeric(as.numeric(sentiment_all[161:180])), results[,"FORESTS_LABEL"])
```

all is good, but one question.  Here, we work with data where we self indicate to the machine what is sad and what is happy text. If i have new documents without indicating what sad, what happy or whats positive and what's negative(suppose, path  one of this document n=read.csv("C:/1/ttt.csv")), how to do, that built model can define what phrase is negative and what positive?

Answer (score 0):

Well, What was all the purpose of building a model to detect what is sad and what is happy? What is you want to achieve? And this does not look like a SO question/answer.

So you are using Supervised Learning in a labeled data (you already know is sad or happy) to learn what defines those classes, so later on you can use the models built for predicting new content where you do not have the label.

So, any transformations done to the data for training you have to do it for the new data coming in, and you ask your model to predict (evaluate) based on this new input data. So you use the prediction as a result. This does not change your model, it is just evaluating it in new data.

Another scenario is that you come with new labeled data, so you want to update your model, so you can retrain it based on the new data you might learn new models that have maybe more features.

In your case you should look at `classify_model` or `classify_models` functions in that package.

Comment: i want load new documents in R and using early built model, predict me what text positive and what negative. Maybe i wrong asked) Imagine i created model. I took 100 documents and manually indicated what tipe of mood. Right? So , we have 100 documents marked as pos or neg
i created train and test sample, all is good. Then my friend give me new 100 documents and said: on the basis of your built model, can you define what 's my document pos and what neg? in case of classify model, i must bind my documents(1-100) with 100 documnets of my friend? 
trainSize=1:100,testSize=101:200?

Comment: No you do not have to bind them, you just have to evaluate your already built model on this new data set, and the output should be positive or negative. You do not touch the previous 100 documents or the model, you just use it for prediction, evaluation.

Comment: Dr VComas, i will try) It seems i understand)